# Recreating corrupted Delphi form

Tags: delphi, forms, reverse-engineering, vcl

I've received source code for a utility I want to adapt, but it appears to have the .dfm files stored in binary format, and one of the .dfm files seems to be coRruPted.
I also have the compiled .exe file.

Is there any way to extract the form from the .exe?

I can see from the relevant .pas file the form type  declaration and the components on the form. How do I go about recreating the form from scratch, and 'attaching' it to the original .pas file?

Comment: You could try any ol' resource editor/extractor as the dfm should be stored in the exe as a resource.

Comment: @Marjan, make that an answer, because it is the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) to recover the DFM from the .exe.

Comment: A superb little utility! In 5 mins I downloaded it, installed it, and extracted the form, and the project now loads without complaint. Thanks. I though it would be a whole lot harder than that!